# update mat table datasource within subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am relatively new to angular and am having a bit of trouble in my typescript of updating a mat table datasource (declared as datasource :any) inside a subscription.

My function below goes away to the adminservice and makes an api call, the function then loops over the returned array and makes another api call via the adminservice to get some more information about the fleet.

At the bottom part of my code is the original method to update the datasource, but without the extra required data. This works fine, and is quite confusing to me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
refresh(): void {
    const data = {};
    const that = this;
    this.adminService.fleets(data).subscribe(result => {

      that.fleetTableData = [];

      result.forEach(function (fleetObject){

        if (typeof fleetObject.fleetTotals === 'undefined'){
          fleetObject.fleetTotals = {};
          fleetObject.fleetTotals.totalVehicles = 0;
          fleetObject.fleetTotals.totalActiveVehicles = 0;
          fleetObject.fleetTotals.totalStatusTestedVehicles = 0;
        }

        that.fleetTableData[fleetObject.fleetId] = fleetObject;

        that.adminService.vehicles(
          {fleetId: fleetObject.fleetId}
        ).subscribe(result2 => {

          result2.forEach(function (vehicleForFleet) {
            var fleetId = vehicleForFleet.fleetId;
            that.fleetTableData[fleetId].fleetTotals.totalVehicles = (that.fleetTableData[fleetId].fleetTotals.totalVehicles + 1);
            if (typeof vehicleForFleet.commissioning !== 'undefined') {
              if (vehicleForFleet.commissioning.commissionStatus === 'tested') {
                that.fleetTableData[fleetId].fleetTotals.totalStatusTestedVehicles = (that.fleetTableData[fleetId].fleetTotals.totalStatusTestedVehicles + 1);
              }
              if (vehicleForFleet.commissioning.commissionStatus === 'active') {
                that.fleetTableData[fleetId].fleetTotals.totalActiveVehicles = (that.fleetTableData[fleetId].fleetTotals.totalActiveVehicles + 1);
              }
            }
          });
        });
      });
      // in subscribe doesn't save to that.datasorce
      that.dataSource.data = new MatTableDataSource(that.fleetTableData);
      that.dataSource.sort = that.sort;
      console.log(that.fleetTableData);
    });
    //out subscribe doest work as it is returning undefined
    // console.log(this.fleetTableData);
    // this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.fleetTableData);
    // this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;


//works
    // const data = {};
    // this.adminService.fleets(data).subscribe(result => {
    //   this.fleets = result;
    //   this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.fleets);
    //   this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    //
    //   console.log(result);
    // });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code it looks like this.datasource is already a MatTableDatasource.  If that is the case then try just setting the .data property to this.fleets instead of a new MatTableDatasource.

```
this.dataSource.data = that.fleetTableData;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two main strategies to address in your code example:

1. You have nested `subscribe()` methods, which is an anti-pattern in RxJS. You should only have one `subscribe()`, otherwise things will quickly break.
2. The logic your executing inside `subscribe()` should instead be handled by RxJS "operators". This will also help with your nested `subscribe()` issue.

Here's the strategy I would recommend.

```
this.adminService.fleets(data).pipe(
  map(result=>{
    // define and return the data you need for adminService.vehicles
  }),
  switchMap(fleetId=>this.adminService.vehicles(fleetId)),
  map(result2=>{
    // Your logic to define and update this.dataSource for your table
  })
).subscribe()
```

The `map()` operator will let you take the emitted value and return a new value.

The `switchMap()` works the same way as `map()` but will let you return a new observable (in this case, your vehicles method that requires the parameter from our first observable.

After that, we use another `map()` operator to take the value emitted from `adminService.vehicles()` and update the state property `this.dataSource`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem at one time when I worked with mat-table, I solved this in this way.

```
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data)
```